# Having trouble drawing a progressive line from coordinate to coordinate in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Extremely new to javascript, and this is my first project! I am building a line graph utilizing Html Canvas and Javascript. I have a function that generates random numbers for X and Y coordinates, which then fills an empty array. I want to plot points and connect them as the Array fills. The end goal is to build a line graph that scales based on the points. I know the code is a little messy (I apologize), and there are other issues, but the problem I am focusing on right now is when the code runs it plots point A, then A B, then A B C, then A B C D, etc. I would like it to plot the points progressively, so it is point A then point B then point C, etc line by line. Hope this makes sense!

From what I have seen from others, it looks like the best way to do this is to reference the previous point in the Array and make sure the line to is from that previous point. I thought that's what I was doing here or at least attempting to do.

```
// Return the x pixel for a graph point
function getXPixel(val) {
    return ((canvas.width - xMarg) / plotArray.length) * val + (xMarg);
}

// Return the y pixel for a graph point
function getYPixel(val) {
    return canvas.height - (((canvas.height - yMarg) / getMaxY()) * val) - yMarg;
}

function plotPoints() {
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#f00';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(getXPixel(0), getYPixel(plotArray[0].Y));
    for (var i = 1; i < plotArray.length; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(getXPixel(i), getYPixel(plotArray[i].Y));
    }
    ctx.stroke();
    label();
    drawCircle();

}


function drawCircle() {
    ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
    for (var i = 0; i < plotArray.length; i++) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(getXPixel(i), getYPixel(plotArray[i].Y), 4, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        ctx.fill();
    }
}

function setPlotHistory(){
    var plotHistory = plotArray.length
    plotArray[plotHistory.res] = {};
    plotArray[plotHistory.moveToX] = plotArray.X;
    plotArray[plotHistory.moveToY] = plotArray.Y;
}


runTest = setInterval(function() {
    var res = { //Create object of results with each test
        X: testsRun,
        Y: getRandomNumber(10,150)
    };
    if (plotArray.length === 5) {
        plotArray.shift();
    }
    plotArray.push(res); //put the result in the array
setPlotHistory(res);
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "Tests Run: " + testsRun;
    testsRun++; //up the number of tests by one 
    plotPoints();

},testInt);
```

Not sure, how much info I should provide and did not want to fill the page up with the entire code, so for reference you can see my full code here https://jsfiddle.net/Crashwin/72vd1osL/3/

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding the desired results correctly... You should clear the canvas and redraw with each call. This will require redrawing the axis. You may want to do an initial draw to setup the graph before the first timer is fired.

Modified plotPoints function:

```
//Draw the line graph
function plotPoints() {
  // clear the canvas for each draw. 
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

  // put the axis back.
  drawAxis();

  // draw all points and lines.
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#f00';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(getXPixel(0), getYPixel(plotArray[0].Y));
  for (var i = 1; i < plotArray.length; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(getXPixel(i), getYPixel(plotArray[i].Y));
  }
  ctx.stroke();
  label();
  drawCircle();
}
```

You should leave the plotArray as is (don't delete points) so it becomes your plot hisotry. No need for setPlotHistory().

Also in the drawAxis function you should set a strokeStyle otherwise it will be in the style defined in plotPoints i.e. #f00.

Modified drawAxis function:

```
function drawAxis() {
  // set axis stroke style
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#333";
  ctx.beginPath(); //new line
  ctx.moveTo(xMarg, 10); //move to (40, 10)
  ctx.lineTo(xMarg, canvas.height - yMarg); // line to (40, height - 40)
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height - yMarg); // line to (width, height - 40)
  ctx.stroke(); //draw lines
}
```

Working example over here: https://jsfiddle.net/8yw5mouz/1/

Ps. This is a pretty nice bit of code. I like how it scales.